How do I resize my variables, that apparently have the same size, so plotly does a scatter plot?
I am trying to make a scatter plot with plotly with just the code
plotly_fig=px.scatter(x=y_test, y=y_pred_SVR2)
and I am getting the following error 'All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument wide_variable_0 is 1, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 7000'. After I verify the variables in Spyders variable explorer they have the same size of 7000
,Spyder variable explorer,
Other posts I found about this error talked about updating the plotly version to 4.something to make it work, but my version is already 5.22.0
Does it have to do with the format? How could I fix this?
Tried reshaping the variables with .reshape(-1,1) to no avail.
